# Hashlib unicode error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unicode

I am trying to hash the password and not able to succeed. this is the code.

```
from hashlib import sha1 as sha_constructor
import random


def generate_sha1(string, salt=None):
    if not isinstance(string, (str, str)):
        string = str(string)
    if isinstance(string, str):
        string = string.encode("utf-8")
    if not salt:
        salt = sha_constructor(str(random.random())).hexdigest()[:5]
    hash = sha_constructor(salt + string).hexdigest()

    return salt, hash


a = generate_sha1('12345')
print(a)
```

I am getting this error.

```
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Python 2, try

```
if isinstance(string, unicode):
```

instead of

```
if isinstance(string, str):
```

Also, `isinstance(string, (str, str)):` doesn't make sense. Should probably be `isinstance(string, (str, unicode)):`

**EDIT** For Python 3, you need to encode the arguments to `sha_constructor()`:

```
arg = str(random.random()).encode('utf-8')
salt = sha_constructor(arg).hexdigest()[:5]
```

etc. If you use the `+` operator, Python will again create a (unicode) string which you have to encode.

Comment: Python 3 doesn't support unicode. I am using Python 3.4

Comment: Please use the correct tags. I've updated my answer.